# Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context. Trying to write in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hi everyone c: I've been working in a Node.js project where I bring data from a JSON file and use it with an API to bring weather, and other things, I'm trying to write the new data into another  JSON file using require.js but it does not seems to work, here is my code, hope you can help me :)

```
const fs = require('fs');
var myObject = {  
                Latitud: data.coord.lat,
                Longitud: data.coord.lon,
                Temperatura: data.main.temp, 
                Ciudad: data.name, 
                Humedad: data.main.humidity,
                Descripción: data.weather[0].description,
                Viento: data.wind.speed,
            };
            // convert JSON object to a string
            const _myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
            // write file to disk
            fs.writeFile('../js/datareceived.json', _myObject, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`File is written successfully!`);
                }

            });
```

and here is the full script

```
async function calcWeather(){ 
    const info = await fetch('../js/data.json') // fetch editable c:
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
    for (var i in info) {
        const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
        const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
        const fs = require('fs');
        const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
        
        fetch(base)
        .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            var myObject = {  
                Latitud: data.coord.lat,
                Longitud: data.coord.lon,
                Temperatura: data.main.temp, 
                Ciudad: data.name, 
                Humedad: data.main.humidity,
                Descripción: data.weather[0].description,
                Viento: data.wind.speed,
            };
            // convert JSON object to a string
            const _myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
            // write file to disk
            fs.writeFile('../js/datareceived.json', _myObject, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`File is written successfully!`);
                }

            });
        });
        
    }
    
};
```

and here is the way I load in my html

```
<script src = "./node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: You cant use the nodejs `fs` package on the client side... there is no filesystem it would have access to in order to write. Can't write to the server because it isnt running on the server and cant write to the user's filesystem as it doesnt have permission

Comment: To start node application  first go through the node js  docs. https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-set-up-your-node-js-and-express-development-environment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment

Comment: tahnk you very much c:

Comment: @PatrickEvans mate, do you know any other way I can write in a JSON without using fs instead?